# Where do I start learning how to administer a Windows 2008 Server, coming from Linux?

Tags: windows

I have next to no Windows experience but a lot of Linux experience. An upcoming engagement will require me to install and run our startup's Rails/MySQL software on a Windows 2008 server. Where do I start learning basic things like how to log in via ssh, how to check out a git repository, how to set up MySQL, etc. though a ssh connection? I don't plan on using VNC, just whatever is the Windows equivalent of a bash session over ssh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are, to some extent, looking at this wrong. The functional equivalent of SSH on windows is remote desktop which *is* a gui environemnt, or really a remote desktop. It is a different world, you can't expect it to behave like *nix. That said, if you want command line level access I'd recommend powershell which blows bash away in many respects.

All that said, you should check out:

- [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) to solve your git access issues
- ruby and rails windows binaries
- MySql windows binaries.

All that said, why are you trying to launch this on windows?

Comment: Because the client is investment firm; they only use Windows servers; and they want to keep the software on their machines.

Comment: I don't know that I'd say rdp is matches up to ssh. More like MMC-> Connect to another computer...

Comment: No, it isn't a 1 for 1 equivalent but for this use case (remote connection) it is what one generally uses.